# Android, how to pass values between two functions?

Tags: java, android, opencv, andengine

I am trying to pass **PosX** and **PosY** values to onLoadScene function, but I couldn't find a solution though tried all ways.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
public class GameField extends LayoutGameActivity implements CvCameraViewListener2
{
      @Override
      public Scene onLoadScene() {
                 this.mScene = new Scene();
                 spritePic1.setPosition((int)PosX- textRegPic1.getWidth()/2,(int) PosY- textRegPic1.getHeight()/2);

    return this.mScene;
        }
        @Override
        public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

                mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();  

                        PosX= Math.round(data2[i]);
                        PosY = Math.round(data2[i+1]);            
               return mRgba; 
        }
}
```

I edited my question. OnLoadScene is LayoutGameActiviy's method. That's why I can't add any parameter to onLoadScene.

Comment: What a question !!, which functions runs first ?

Comment: While this question's already been answered (correctly), I have to ask - how many other ways are there to pass a value from one function to another? You say that you "tried all ways;" what did you try?

Comment: You are so right. I cant explain exactly. But I cant add any parameter to onLoadScene because of LayoutGameActivity's method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  public Scene onLoadScene(float PosX,float PosY) {//PosX,PosY is float you can take as per your choice
             this.mScene = new Scene();
             spritePic1.setPosition((int)PosX- textRegPic1.getWidth()/2,(int) PosY- textRegPic1.getHeight()/2);

return this.mScene;
    }
```

For calling function

```
onLoadScene(PosX,PosY)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I can't add any parameter to onLoadScene because Thats GameActivity's method.

Comment: define float PosX,PosY globally and put value in posX,PosY where you want to give and then use that PosX,PosY inside onLoadScene()

Comment: I already defined as global and put values in onCameraFrame, but result return zero inside onLoadScene. Maybe problem is that two function have to work simultaneuosly ?

Comment: I fixed the problem. Problem was about updating Scene. Just added update handler and it worked. Anyway thanks for advice!